# Why avr-as doesn't work?

Tags: avr, assembly

I've got the following program, in AVR assembly:

```
.DEF    WR = R16

.ORG 0

SER    WR
OUT    0x24, WR
```

When I call `avr-as beeep.s`, where beeep.s contains the previous code, I get an error message:

```
beeep.s: Assembler messages:
beeep.s:1: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.def'
beeep.s:5: Error: constant value required
beeep.s:5: Error: register number above 15 required
beeep.s:6: Error: constant value required
```

I can't find the origin of my error... What did I do wrong ?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to compile the code written for `avrasm` with GNU `as`, which seem to have a different directives (which are not machine instructions but "pseudo-ops").

Comment: @EugeneSh. So what instructions should I use ? Or, what Assembler ?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuasm.html#SEC67). Or just use the Atmel's provide assembler.

Comment: @EugeneSh. But `.dev` is in this instructions set, and the same error message occurs when I replace `.DEV` with `.dev`...

Comment: Yes, but the meaning and usage are completely different.

Comment: @EugeneSh. And which Assembler does support the syntax I'm using ?

Comment: [This one](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/) I guess..

Comment: @EugeneSh. But, it seams that this assembler is only available on windows, is there an equivalent assembler available on linux ?

Comment: It looks like it's windows only. In this case you will have to migrate it to GNU assembler.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks, you can post your answer, I'll mark it as the good one !

Answer (score 1):

Change `.DEF` with `.EQU`:

```
.EQU    WR, R16

.ORG 0

SER    WR
OUT    0x24, WR
```

Answer (score 0):

As described on http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/assembler.html
one should NOT be using avr-as directly but use avr-gcc instead.

E.g: avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega8 -x assembler-with-cpp example.s

See Note [2] of the example program on the page to see how to assign symbolic name to register.